# CompletableFuture<List<CardItem>> to Mono object

Tags: java-8, stream, mono, flux, completable-future

i have an api that returns CompletableFuture

where  CardItem{
cardType
cardStatus
cardDetails
}

but i'd like to iterate through the CompletableFuture and build a parent children object class where if cardType = Header is the parent. and the rest of the CardItems are children.

like Mono

where CardItemRO {
cardType= header
cardStatus
cardDetails
List
}

Answer (score 0):

You have map the list of completableFuture to List of Mono. then use Flux.fromIterable to iterate the list of Mono's

```
 Mono<List<CardItem>>  mapCompletableFutureToMono=listOfCompletableFuture.map { Mono.fromFuture(it) }.toList()

    Flux.fromIterable(mapCompletableFutureToMono).flatMap { it }.collectList().map{cardItem-> // do something}
```